# How to improve formula calculation with PHPExcel?

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

I'm new to PHPExcel, and I've scoured the Googles, but not finding much for my specific problem here. I'm finding that updating/evaluating the formulas in my sheet is being *really* slow.

I've got a pretty small excel file on which I'm doing some very basic goal-seeking (goal seeking done in PHP, end result calculation done in excel sheet). I've got it working accurately, but the speed is absolutely killing me. It appears that the formula calculation is to blame -- **how can formula calculations/updates be sped up?**

Unfortunately, I can't post a copy of the excel file as the contents are a trade secret for my company, but it's nothing out of the ordinary. Very simple arithmetic in the formulas. The only thing I can think of that might have an effect here is that some of the cell-dependency chains can be somewhat long (15-ish dependencies).

As you can see from the output below, we're only executing 11 iterations for the goal seeking, and taking a total of 4-5 seconds. Since this will be an AJAX service, I really need it to be faster than that.

### Code

This is very quick and dirty proof-of-concept code, please bear with me:

```
<?php

Stopwatch::start();

$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify( './example.xlsx' );
var_dump( 'FileType: '.$inputFileType );
Stopwatch::rel( 'identify filetype' );

$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader( $inputFileType );
$objReader->setReadDataOnly( true );
$filterSubset = new ReadFilter( 1, 35, range( 'A', 'J' ));
$objReader->setReadFilter( $filterSubset );
Stopwatch::rel( 'create reader' );

$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load( $inputFileName );
Stopwatch::rel( 'load file' );

$data = $objPHPExcel->getSheetByName( 'Data' );
$inputCell  = $data->getCell( 'B9' );
$outputCell = $data->getCell( 'B35' );
Stopwatch::rel( 'get cells' );

goalSeek( $inputCell, $outputCell, '0.10', 1, 5 );







function goalSeek( $inputCell, $outputCell, $targetValue ) {
    $cellValue = function() use ( &$outputCell, $precision ) {
        return round( $outputCell->getCalculatedValue(), $precision );
    };

    $setValue = function( $value ) use ( &$inputCell, &$objPHPExcel, $cellValue ) {
        $inputCell->setValue( $value );
        PHPExcel_Calculation::getInstance( $objPHPExcel )->clearCalculationCache(); // -- clear cache so updates are calculated
        Stopwatch::rel( 'goal-seek' );
    };

    // -- very basic goal seeking psuedo-code
    while( $stillHunting ) { // -- outside tolerance
        $setValue( $newInputValue );
    }
};

class ReadFilter implements PHPExcel_Reader_IReadFilter {
    private $_startRow = 0;
    private $_endRow   = 0;
    private $_columns  = [];

    public function __construct( $startRow, $endRow, $columns ) {
        $this->_startRow = $startRow;
        $this->_endRow   = $endRow;
        $this->_columns  = $columns;
    }

    public function readCell( $column, $row, $worksheetName = '' ) {
        if( $row >= $this->_startRow && $row <= $this->_endRow ) { // -- valid row
            if( in_array( $column, $this->_columns )) { // -- valid column
                return true;
            }
        }
        // else (implicit)

        return false;
    }
}
```

### Output

```
string 'FileType: Excel2007' (length=19)

array (size=2)
  'rel' => 
    array (size=17)
      'identify' => float 0.008597135543823242
      'create reader' => float 0.0001199245452880859
      'load file' => float 0.387645959854126
      'get cells' => float 5.292892456054688E-5
      'goal-seek' => float 0.4194750785827637
      'goal-seek2' => float 0.3829901218414307
      'goal-seek3' => float 0.3478608131408691
      'goal-seek4' => float 0.3471150398254395
      'goal-seek5' => float 0.3569440841674805
      'goal-seek6' => float 0.378180980682373
      'goal-seek7' => float 0.3683559894561768
      'goal-seek8' => float 0.3778479099273682
      'goal-seek9' => float 0.3664979934692383
      'goal-seek10' => float 0.4503841400146484
      '_avg' => float 0.2794940630594889
      '_untilStop' => float 0.5339441299438477
  'total' => float 4.726345062255859
```

Comment: Solution: rewrite the PHPExcel calculation engine yourself to make it faster...... there is no magic method `CalculationEngine::runFaster()` with a default setting of slow that you can change

Comment: @MarkBaker, I never asked for a magic `runFaster` method. I'm looking for feedback about if I'm somehow doing something inefficiently, or if there are some settings or tweaks that might help it run faster. I picked up some speed tweaking the caching approach, so I can only assume there's a few more optimizations to be made.

Comment: Without knowing the formula, it's almost impossible to answer; though you are passing a couple of unused parameters to `goalSeek()`.... while the sheet may contain IPO and not be viable to show here, a question as "vague" as "how can formula calculations/updates be sped up?" with no real information isn't giving anything to work with, and can't really be answered

Comment: @MarkBaker the `goalSeek()` method isn't the slow one. The slowness is coming from `$cell->getCalculatedValue()`

Comment: Then `how can formula calculations/updates be sped up?` is slow, but can't easily be speeded up without rewriting it, or possibly refactoring your formula for the cell

Comment: @MarkBaker as the question states, the cell formulas are very basic arithmetic, the only concern is the dependency tree for the cells. I don't see how my formulas could be any simpler other than the dependencies. Are you saying that there's nothing else to be done to make things faster? I know it's a different story, but excel itself is doing these calculations FAR faster.

Comment: Excel is written in C, PHPExcel (including the calculation engine) is written in raw PHP...... if you want to execute these calculations at the speed of MS Excel itself, then you need to use MS Excel itself

Comment: In real terms, if you still want to use PHP, then you'd probably be better using a dedicated PHP script specifically tailored to the formula that you're using, rather than a more generic formula parser like that built-into PHPExcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, one possible solution that might speed things up if you're recalculating the same formula, but with different values in related cells is to parse the formula once, and only once, but execute multiple times.

`getCalculatedValue()` calls two methods; the first is `parseFormula()` which accepts the formula as a string, and builds a parser stack (as an array) of steps for the execution of that formula; the second (a private method, so you'd need to change that to public in Calculation.php) is `processTokenStack()` which accepts 3 arguments, the token stack generated by the call to `parseFormula()`, the cell ID (as a string) and the cell object.

It might be possible for you to execute the parseFormula() step only once, and then call the `processTokenStack()` for each iteration, which would eliminate the parse step for all but the first iteration

Comment: It may boost performance a bit; but it certainly won't give you MS Excel levels of performance, or even those of a custom function written especially for your formula

Comment: Looks like this made about a 20% performance improvement! (at least with my basic tests). If you have any other ideas that might speed things up, let me know! Pull request here: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/pull/863

Comment: Did this work for you? I have similar problem with slow calculation.

Comment: @MarkBaker I want to try your suggestions, but I am not sure what you mean by passing the third argument which is cell object? What is the cell object? How do I get it?

Comment: @vick SO really isn't the place for full-blown tutorials into how to code in PHP. The `cell object` is the object that has the `getCalculatedValue()` method

Comment: this object? $excel->getActiveSheet()

Comment: No! That's returns the worksheet (sheet) object.... the method name should give some clue to the type of object that it returns.... `$data->getCell( 'B9' );` returns a `cell` object (specifically the cell object for cell B9)..... the clue is in the name:`getCell()` which means that it __gets__ a __cell__ object.... we do try to make names meaningful

Comment: @MarkBaker I realized what is taking time for me is not the call to getCalculatedValue() but it's when I clear cache using clearCalculationCache(). I am doing a goalseek so I am reading a cell value about 100 times until the goalseek meets it's desired value and I am calling clearCalculationCache() on each iteration before I call getCalculatedValue(). Do you know of any means of optimizing this?

Comment: @MarkBaker let me know if I should open a new Question where I ask my query with more details?