# Duplicate Formula Dynamically in PhpExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am new to PHPExcel. I wanted to duplicate the formula with updated cell values. For example,

In cell C1 the formula is (A1 * B1).
I am copying the rows from cell range A1:C1 to A5:C5.

The cell values are getting copied successfully. But The formula is not updating. I wanted to update the formula as (A2 * B2), (A3 * B3) etc..

Note: I cannot update the formula manually. The only way I can do is, Read the formula, parse it and then update the cell values accordingly.

I have tried this,

[How to improve formula calculation with PHPExcel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049614/how-to-improve-formula-calculation-with-phpexcel/36067485#36067485)
I have changed the private **processTokenStack** function to public, But it is throwing "Call to Undefined method PHPExcel_Calculation::processTokenStack() " error. 
Kindly guide me. 
Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPExcel provides functionality for this in the `PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper` class (the same functionality that adjusts cell references when you insert/delete rows and columns).

The method is `updateFormulaReferences()`, which has the following signature:

```
/**
 * Update references within formulas
 *
 * @param     string    $pFormula    Formula to update
 * @param     string    $pBefore    Insert before this cell
 * @param     int       $pNumCols    Number of columns to insert
 * @param     int       $pNumRows    Number of rows to insert
 * @param     string    $sheetName  Worksheet name/title
 * @return    string    Updated formula
 * @throws    PHPExcel_Exception
 */
```

As an example of use:

```
$formula = '=(A1 * B1)';
echo $formula, PHP_EOL;

$referenceHelper = PHPExcel_ReferenceHelper::getInstance();

$adjustedFormula = $referenceHelper->updateFormulaReferences($formula, 'A1', 0, 1);

echo $adjustedFormula, PHP_EOL;
```

which will output

```
=(A1 * B1)
=(A2 * B2)
```